# Cant't take an object id from a parse object and use it in other sections of code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Ive spent countless hours trying to figure out why I can't seem to take the object id of an object that has been saved to parse and use it in other sections of my code.  Yes I have searched and found topics about this on stack overflow and other websites and I have read the parse.com documentation but none of the answers will allow me to fix this issue.  I am pretty new to coding and I am only familiar with swift at the moment.  If you can help me figure this out I would more than appreciate your help.

I declare objectID as a string variable at the top of the code.  Later when a send button is tapped I save the data to parse successfully and attempt to capture the datas objectId by passing the objectID variable to the saveToParse function as an inout.  The project does not show any errors.  The code builds and runs.  NSLog(id) shows me the proper objectId that I want in the console.  However it does not show anything when NSLog(self.objectID) is called outside of the function.

Like I said, I'm trying to use this objectId outside the function in other parts of the code, but it just doesn't want to save the objectId to my variable.  I've tried many other methods and this is the closest I have got to making it work.

Im new at this so hope I've explained my situation clearly, if you need any more information to solve this don't hesitate to ask.  Thanks for reading :)

```
var objectID:String = String() // declared at the top (underneath Class)

@IBAction func sendQuestionTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    // Send question and answers to Parse
        saveToParse(&objectID)



    // Save Question object ID

        NSLog(self.objectID)  // Test if objectID is still Question.objectId

    // Move to the results view controller with information
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toResultsSegue", sender: self)


}

func saveToParse(inout id:String) {

    var Question = PFObject(className:"Question")
    Question["question"] = questionToPass
    Question["answers"] = arrayToPass

    Question.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                id = Question.objectId!
                NSLog(id)

            }

        }

        else {

            // There was a problem, check error.description
            if error != nil {

                NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're expecting `self.objectID` to be set as soon as the `saveToParse` call returns, you're not considering the asynchronous nature of doing processing in the background and then calling `dispatch_async`.

Comment: Also, with Parse there is rarely any need to use the `objectID` directly - simply store a reference to the `PFObject` instance itself.

Comment: @ Phillip, Thats embarrassing. I didn't realize that.  I just ended up using Question.save() instead of the .saveInBackgroundWithBlock method.  It works but inside the console i get a message saying "Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread."  Im not sure if that will cause any issues.

Comment: @ Paul, In the parse documentation it shows that to retrieve specific items you insert the objectId. example: query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ").  Are you saying its a better idea to set a new column in the row and access it that way instead?

Comment: @JeffDicket Parse already has the `objectId` built into their classes. If you take a look at the Data Browser, you will see that all objects have a column called `objectId`. What exactly is it you need to use the `objectId` for anyways?

Comment: @lightice11, I use the objectId to retrieve the data that was previously sent to Parse. Basically send data on one phone, and then retrieve it on another.  So to retrieve the data I use the objectId, which is how the parse documents examples are written. example: query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ")

Comment: That sounds logical, and it should work the way you're trying to do it